# Generate dynamic tables using datatable with order, limit, search functionality

Tags: php, mysql, database, datatable

I am using jQuery datatble server side processing (https://datatables.net).

First i am sharing my database structure you are aware about idea that how the data stored in database and how to render it.

Table Row Master:

[image]

Table Column Master:

[image: Table Column master]

Table Data Master:

[image: Table Data master]

These are the three tables

And I am putting query for the datatable with limit and searching but i can not achieve it with ordering any column because all data save in one db table table **(Table Data master)**  so can you please provide solution to do this or suggest me any other way to do for it.

```
$strQuery = "SELECT tc.id as column_id,tr.id as row_id,td.data_value,td.link_type,td.link_value,td.is_new_tab FROM 
                    (
                        SELECT tc.id as column_id,tr.id as row_id,td.data_value,td.link_type,td.link_value,td.is_new_tab 
                        from table_data td  
                            INNER join table_columns tc on tc.id=td.column_id and tc.table_id='1'  
                            INNER join table_rows tr on tr.id=td.row_id and tr.table_id='1' 
                            where td.table_id='1' and td.deletedBy=0   ".$strWhere."
                            GROUP BY td.id  order by tr.isSequence ASC,tc.isSequence ASC 
                    )
                as tdata
                INNER JOIN  table_data td on td.row_id = tdata.row_id
                INNER JOIN  table_rows tr ON tr.id = td.row_id
                INNER JOIN  table_columns tc ON tc.id = td.column_id
GROUP by td.id ORDER BY tr.isSequence asc,tc.isSequence asc ";

$cols = ((int)$_POST['cols']); // number of cols 
$top = 0;
if(isset($_POST['start']))
{
    $top = ($cols) * ((int)$_POST['start']);
}
$limit = $cols *10;
if(isset($_POST['length']))
{
    $limit = $cols * ((int)$_POST['length']);
}
$strQuery .= " LIMIT ".$top.",".$limit." ";
```

I want to fetch 10 rows then I want 60 records and prepare the array as row and cols array

```
foreach ($list_data['data'] as $tableData) {
            $rowData[$tableData["row_id"]][$tableData["column_id"]] = $tableData;
        }
```

This is how I am getting final array but I am not getting order by functionality in this. so please provide me the suggestion.

Comment: After your `group by`, the only columns that remain are the ones in your outer `select` (first line), and `isSequence ` is not among them. You cannot order by a column that is not part of your resultset. Which is what the error message you should get would tell you, so please always provide any errors to help identify the problem. So much to know what is wrong. To get assistance on how to solve it, you would need to provide an sql fiddle with some sample data, as well as the desired result, as it's very hard to walk through your datamodel, you unfortunately used a very abstract data model.

Comment: As a general note: The "s" in sql stands for "structured", and if you have structured data (e.g. a table with 20 columns), then ordering by a column is as simple as `select * from table order by columnname`. While you gain some flexibility with your abstract model (you can dynamically add columns, you can store very sparse data), you lose out on a lot of features that naturally emerge from a standard design, e.g. consistency/integrity checks like ...

Comment: datatype/fixed structure/not null(=required) columns/foreign keys/primary keys (which represents a lot of the things that make a relational database a relational database), optimizing tools like indexes (to e.g. support ordering), administration tools like userrights to specific tables, and generally having easier queries. So unless you really need such a design, you should consider doing it a more standard way, it might make your life a lot easier. You may also e.g. want to consider some orm to add some abstraction layer.